# Why is Latin considered a dead language, but Old High German simply a precursor to modern German?

Tags: historical-linguistics, latin, italian

Or, to put it another way: If the Church hadn't preserved Latin, would it even be considered a different language from Italian as opposed to simply an older form in the development of the Italian language?

Comment: Linguists usually consider Latin to be a precursor of French, and OHG is a dead language. If there is such a trend, it has to do with the name of the language. Sanskrit and Latin are the exceptional cases, English, Mongolian, Greek etc. is the more general case, that the dead language and the modern language are given the same name.

Comment: It helps when there's only one language, or one prominent language at times maybe, deriving from the older language. Latin turned into a whole subfamily, and "Latin" was already a well-established name, aside from the fact that calling it "Old Italian" would make questions like "why not Old French?" obvious, and also these names are already used for earlier phases of those daughter languages (well, for French at least).

Comment: It isn't. On the dead/alive scale, Old High German is as dead as Latin. And looking at languages from the historical perspective, some form of Latin (vulgar Latin) is the precursor of the modern Romance languages.

Answer (score -2):

Pondering over [question not very related] I happened on *still live (painting), inanimate*, that in some language translates as "dead" (cp perhaps *dead weight*). Latin does not change as its grammar fossilized, deemed perfect by some, irregardless of new nouns being added.

The second part of your question has been answered before [at what point does a language become its descendent](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/28612/at-what-point-does-a-language-become-its-descendant/30454?r=SearchResults#30454). Spoiler: when (mutual?) interligability is lost; that's necessarily a fuzzy concept.